# Import xx.sql file to execute by using Ebean

Tags: sql, playframework-2.0, ebean

Is there any way to execute SQLs directly read from SQL files(xx.sql) in Ebean?

For example, if I had a SQL file including several SQL statements (values already written in the file), is there any way to execute this SQL file by using Ebean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options out of the box:

1. Play [evolutions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Evolutions) are meant to updating DB schema, so you can use them also for inserting initial data (if they are flat, and will not contain relations to the objects not created yet), sample evolution for MySQL:

   ```
   # --- !Ups
   INSERT INTO your_table (some_field) VALUES ('New value');

   # --- !Downs
   DELETE FROM your_table WHERE some_field = 'New value`;
   ```
2. Use Global object and insert initial data using common Ebean's way:

   ```
   public void onStart(Application app) {
       if (YourModel.find.findRowCount() == 0) {
           YourModel newItem = new YourModel();
           newItem.someField = "New value";
           newItem.save();

           YourModel newItem2 = new YourModel();
           // etc.... 
       }
   }
   ```

For the second approach you can check the way how to read YAML file holding initial data with [Global object of Zentask sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/Global.java) (the file with sample is placed in `conf` directory)

**Edit:**

Take a closer look to the [initial-data.yml](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/conf/initial-data.yml), there are also relations between tasks and projects, so they have fixed `id` values. So you need do the same in your yaml:

```
projects:

    - !!models.Project
        id:         1
        name:       Play 2.0   
        folder:     Play framework

tasks:

    - !!models.Task
        title:      Fix the documentation
        done:       false
        folder:     Todo
        project:    !!models.Project
                        id: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the second option, I have a problem like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932111/play-framework-inserting-initial-data-more-than-20-items-per-one-model . So, I tried to use the first option, but my initial data is not flat. It is the reason that I asked is there any third option to insert initial-data.

Comment: @user1331366 Check my edited answer it shouldn't 'jump' when using fixed values of `id` field. I don't know why's that (this jumping), I observed similar behaviour in `H2 in-mem` however when you are creating new objects with app it doesn't matter.

Comment: I checked your edited answer right before. It works perfectly. Thank you again.